# How do you breed an Equinox Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

A dragon is now available in the marketplace called an Equinox Dragon. What is the best combination of dragons to breed this dragon?  What is the breeding time?  Also, is this a limited dragon?

Comment: doesn't it get tiring asking these questions after a while just for the gold badge :P

Comment: [It's a legitimate strategy!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLMYTQUw8Lc)

Comment: The badge is cute, but I'm also just trying to make Arqade a place where folks go to find the answers. Obviously many thousands do. :). Awesome link @agent86.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazing and water are good, worked first time for me.

It is limited and it takes 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Breeding time is 24 hours.... Limited since it's only around for the Equinox... and it says the elements are the moon and the sun so idk what breeding yet... or if it's simply just the sun and the moon

Comment: I thought sun and moon also, but it won't let me breed my sun dragon with anything else but a sun dragon... Same for my moon. She can only be bred with another moon or blue moon dragon... bleh.